# How to create the scrolling effect like duo.google.com?

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, html

https://duo.google.com/
As you see, it just like scrolling with canvas.

I had found a similar way to do this.
https://codyhouse.co/?p=634
Unfortunately, they are not same and "background-attachment: fixed;"
is not work in mobile device

I had also tried to use z-index and position setting.
However, it doesn't work due to some fixed layers cannot be overlay.

So, may I ask for the concept or reference to do the same scrolling effect with duo.google.com? Hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

This might come somewhat close to what u want to do.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/h0qmj6p0/1/)

To make the phone not overflow to the blue box, we make use of two properties particularly.

1. Assign all `divs` inside `container` css rule `position: relative;`
2. Assign `.red` div, css rule `overflow: hidden;`